# How can I make "required" UITextFields?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c

I have a ViewController that contains a series of UITextFields (a form) that my app users fill out and submit (by tapping on a UIButton). The data is posted to an external database (MySQL), and it all works great. However, I want all of the UITextField's to be "required"; in other words, the "submit" button shouldn't post data unless all fields are filled in (contain values). Does anyone know how I might go about doing that? See my code below.

**ViewController.h**

```
-(IBAction)addParty:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *guestphone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *guestemail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *guestsize;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addParty:(id)sender
{


    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"guestfirst=%@&guestlast=%@&guestphone=%@&guestemail=%@&guestsize=%@", firstname.text, lastname.text, guestphone.text, guestemail.text, guestsize.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", strURL);


    NSData *postData = [strURL dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"postgl.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

        [thankyou setHidden:NO];         
    }
    else
    {
         [thankyou setHidden:YES];
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before you send your request, you can do a nested if statement, checking for empty string values.

so if you have 3 text fields that are required, 3 nested if statements would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much; nesting in if/else statements is what ended up working for me. Posted the actual code in an answer below incase anyone else needed it :)

Comment: Why would you suggest 3 nested `if` statements? What if there were 20 text fields? 20 nested `if` statements would get silly.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to set the delegate for the textfields to be the UIViewController.

Implement the following in the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Once this is implemented you should have a method like the following:

```
- (BOOL)enableSubmitButton
{
    for (UITextField *textField in @[self.firstname, self.lastname, self.guestphone, self.guestemail, self.guestsize]) {
        if (textfield.text.length == 0) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Then you should have an IBOutlet for the button set and you can call inside the shouldChangeCharactersInRange the enableSubmitButton and set the button enabled to that i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;

or could be UIBarButtonItem

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *submitButton;

self.submitButton.enabled = [self enableSubmitButton];
```

Comment: Used a part of your answer with my own and it ended up working :) See what I did below (posted the answer for anyone else curious about it). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For future viewers, it's worth noting this can be done very easily using KVO collection operators.

```
- (IBAction)addParty:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *required = @[
                          self.firstname,
                          self.lastname,
                          self.guestphone,
                          self.guestemail,
                          self.guestsize
    ];

    if([[required valueForKeyPath:@"text.@min.length"] intValue] == 0)
    {
        [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];
        [thankyou setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [pleasefinish setHidden:YES];
        [thankyou setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting in if/else statements is what ended up working for me (e.g. that way if 3/5 fields are filled out, data won't post unless 5/5 are complete). Thanks everyone for your help!

```
  - (IBAction)addParty:(id)sender

{

    for (UITextField *textFielda in @[self.firstname]) {
        if (textFielda.text.length == 0) {

             [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];

        }

        for (UITextField *textFieldb in @[self.lastname]) {
            if (textFieldb.text.length == 0) {

                [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];

            }

        for (UITextField *textFieldc in @[self.guestphone]) {
                if (textFieldc.text.length == 0) {

                    [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];

                }

        for (UITextField *textFieldd in @[self.guestemail]) {
                    if (textFieldd.text.length == 0) {

                        [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];

                    }

        for (UITextField *textFielde in @[self.guestsize]) {
                        if (textFielde.text.length == 0) {

                            [pleasefinish setHidden:NO];

                        }

        else {

         [pleasefinish setHidden:YES];

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"guestfirst=%@&guestlast=%@&guestphone=%@&guestemail=%@&guestsize=%@", firstname.text, lastname.text, guestphone.text, guestemail.text, guestsize.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", strURL);


    NSData *postData = [strURL dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"postgl.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];



    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

       [thankyou setHidden:NO];

    }
    else
    {
       [thankyou setHidden:YES];
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }


}
    }

                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a really ugly solution to the problem. There is no point to nested for-loops and there is no point to a for-loop that iterates a single value. Imagine the code if you had 20 text fields. A proper solution would look the same whether you had 2 or 200 text fields. Please consider using a single loop as shown in the answer by @darren102.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy! Originally I ended up going the route that @darren102 suggested, but it only worked if ALL fields had a value of 0 (not if 3/5 fields had a value of 0)?

Comment: A simple change would be to keep a count in the loop. Once the minimum is reached you can return `YES`. I don't see how the code in your answer supports 3/5 versus requiring all.

Comment: @rmaddy As lengthy as my code is (lol), it reads:  "if any individual field has a value of 0, don't pass go", whereas darren102's reads "if all fields have a value of 0, don't pass go". But you're right, I'm certain there's a more productive way to achieve this.